# Asp.Net Identity - A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a code first EF application. The database has been created. Now I am trying to implement Login/Registration module using the Asp.Net Identity. I click the Register link but it gives me the above error.

Web.config:

```
...
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnStr_Dev" 
         connectionString="Data Source = DELL-MyName; Initial Catalog = MyDB_Dev; user id = sa; password=myPassword;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <!--<add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MyApp-20170328111628.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MyApp-20170328111628;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
...
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory 
          type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="Data Source = DELL-MyName; Initial Catalog = MyDB_Dev; user id = sa; password=myPassword;" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```

Is there something that needs to be set separately?

Answer (score 0):

1- Use below connection string. I am using here SQL express instance. Replace it with the name you use to connect through sql management studio.

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnStr_Dev" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDB_Dev;User ID=sa;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=20;Max Pool Size=100;Connection Timeout=300;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

2- Remove `<entityFramework>` tag from config file. You dont need it.

3- Make sure you are passing 'ConnStr_Dev' as string to DbContext constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the file IdentityModel.cs in the Models folder. In the ApplicationDbContext constructor the name of the connection string is passed in to the base class constructor - this needs to match the name of the your connection string in your web.config

[image]

[image]

So in your case

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnStr_Dev" 
         connectionString="Data Source = DELL-MyName; Initial Catalog = MyDB_Dev; user id = sa; password=myPassword;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>




public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("ConnStr_Dev", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```